# Match rows after group by multiple columns in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

How to queryrows after group by with multiple columns.

Below is the table :

```
ord_num | loc | void | pay_type
-----------------------
10   |   a101  | Y   | CR
10   |   a101  | N   | AB
10   |   a101  | N   | CH
11   |   a102  | N   | CR
11   |   a102  | Y   | CR
12   |   a103  | Y   | JK
13   |   a104  | N   | CR
13   |   a104  | Y   | JK
14   |   a104  | Y   | CR
```

I need rows with ord_num, loc where pay_type contains only 'CR'.

I am expecting the query result below :

```
ord_num | loc
------------------
11   |   a102
14   |   a104
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select ord_num, loc
from table
group by ord_num, loc
having max(pay_type) = min(pay_type) and max(pay_type) = 'CR'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct ord_ num, loc
from yourTable 
where pay_type = 'CR'
```